# Как обновить родительскую ветку до новых изменений без петель

Tags: git

Я создал ветку, сделал изменения и `rebase`'нул её на родительскую ветку. Теперь я хочу, чтобы у меня старая ветка содержала те же новые изменения (вторую теперь можно и удалить).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я делаю `merge` B в A, у меня получается такая страшная конструкция (справа). Как можно сделать, чтобы всё выглядело как посередине?

Comment: `git merge --ff B`

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Я сидел через GUI (консольные команды я выучу), и там надо было выбрать fast-forward.